# Not getting connection in servlet but getting connection in normal java class

Tags: java

I want a connection in a servlet but my connection is not returning in a servlet class but it is returning in a normal java class. What can be the issue and how can i resolve it?

I am using Eclipse IDE, JAVA 8 and Tomcat as a server

**Java Class**

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","user","pass");
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(con);
    }

}
```

**Servlet Class**

```
    @WebServlet("/MainServlet")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    public MainServlet() {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","user","pass");

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(con);
    }
}
```

**Edit1:**

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="MainServlet" method="post">

<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
null
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.test.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note: the null that I am getting there is because I printed the connection con variable in my servlet

Comment: Do you make the POST request to "/MainServlet"?

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo yes

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @k314159 i will update the error message in my question

Comment: Error message seems clear to me: You have not correctly deployed a JDBC driver on your Servlet container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.JDBC.driver.OracleDriver**

This means that the servlet cannot find the jar file.

My issue was resolved by putting the jar file in the WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

- First check that you have access to your servlet?
- Are you using the example without or with an IDE?
- Check that the servlet is compiled

And `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` mean it not not see the JDBC you should download the driver and put it in the `WEB-INF/lib`

Hope this could help you.

Comment: 1. How can i check that if i have access to my servlet??
2. I am using Eclipse IDE
3. How can i check if my servlet is compiled?

Comment: Normally post awaiting data? Try the test without connecting to the database and you will see if you can call it first.

Comment: If the single call doesn't work, that means you can't call your servlet.

Here are some simple servlet examples [Servlet examples](https://github.com/segandiaye/JEE-PROJECTS)  but which `web.xml` rather than annotations, that might help you with the documentation.

Comment: The servlet is working because it is printing "null" which is written in my servlet code

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` mean it not not see the JDBC you should download the driver and put it in the `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: exactly Sega GOOD JOB, idk how this didnt came on my mind, thank you

Comment: If this resolve your answer can you mark it resolved. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Servlet - similar to a Spring Controller -  should not make a connection to the database. You should place database logic in a separate class and then instantiate that class in the Servlet and call the method that performs database operations from that servlet. That is separating database logic from the servlet.

Having said that -- you should check if you have the database driver file properly configured in your project. IN some cases, connection issues are related to the database driver file.

**Updated** - i was correct in assuming your error was related to the database driver file. Look at the exception:

**ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**

**You need to ensure the Oracle driver file is included in your project**.

Comment: I am using odjbc6.jar file and it is on my project build path, if it was not there then then the error would have arrived with normal java class too
Second thing, i tried seprating database login in a separate java class and calling that method in my servlet but no luck

Comment: You may have included it within your class path - but when it executes the servlet - its not finding the database driver file -- hence the exception.

Comment: So what do you think i should do here, how can i make the servlet find my database driver file

Comment: Try placing the database driver file in the projects /lib folder.